# SQL query with criteria builder

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have SQL query and i need to translate it into criteria builder

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(`quantity`) AS quantity, price, margin, category_id 
  FROM `product_sale` 
 WHERE time = '2017-02-06 22:39:11' 
 GROUP BY `product_id`
```

I started well, but do not know how to go on

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<SaleProduct> cq = cb.createQuery(SaleProduct.class);

    Root<SaleProduct> saleProduct = cq.from(SaleProduct.class);
    cq.multiselect(saleProduct.get("productId"), cb.sum(saleProduct.<Integer>get("quantity")));
    Predicate filterCondition = getFilterCondition(cb, saleProduct, filters);
    filterCondition = cb.between(saleProduct.<Date>get("time"), dateTo, dateFrom);
    filterCondition = cb.and(filterCondition, cb.equal(saleProduct.get("storeId"), storeId));

    cq.where(filterCondition);
    cq.groupBy(saleProduct.get("productId"));
```

Comment: So start off by converting it to JPQL. JPQL refers to classes and fields not tables and columns, and nobody here sees your entities, so post the JPQL you are trying to achieve first, along with your entities, and then comment on what error you get

Comment: The first problem you need to address is that you cannot `GROUP BY` on just the `product_id` column based on the SQL you showed.  The values for `price`, `margin`, and `category_id` would either need to be included or removed as you haven't mentioned then in the `GROUP BY` and they're not aggregates.